# Как выводить результат перебора массива только один раз?

Tags: javascript

По нажатию на элемент выполняется перебор массива с данными, но проблема заключается в том, что результат выводится несколько раз, в зависимости от длинны самого массива. Как можно это пофиксить, и возвращать результат единожды?

Code: https://playcode.io/738029/

Comment: вы задали уже 8 вопросов, но всё ещё не знаете, как оформлять код на Stackoverflow? Вам стоит ознакомиться со справкой (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  +  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Вы проверяете статус для каждой бомбы и выводите его. Логчино что  выводе получается множество проверок good. Чтобы этого избежать просто сотрите вывод `console.log('good!');`

Для того, чтобы узнать, попал ли человек в бомбу можете перед циклом проверки завести флаг `isSafeMove' равный true и, если нашлась бомба, что сработала - менять его значение на false.

Также, наверное, можно выставить свойство isBomb сразу у объекта, на который кликаете и тогда не придётся проверять весь массив.